# VFAT as kernel module

Tags: drivers, kernel, fat32

Is it possible to have VFAT in Ubuntu installed as module?

There is no fat|vfat module listed in `lsmod`, so I suspect it is somehow built-in in kernel (Ubuntu 18.04/20.04).

I would like to add some printk() for learning purposes, so I need to recompile fat filesystem code.
Do I need to recompile whole kernel to do that?